# Generate numbers 1 to 1000000 in MS Access using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am looking for a simple clean method to obtain the sequence {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,...,1000000} in MS Access SQL. I thought of creating a table with a column that numbers from 1 to 100000 however, this is inefficient.

Is there a way of generating numbers 1 to 10000000 in MS Access using SQL?

I tried the `GENERATE_SERIES()` function but MS Access SQL does not support this function.

```
id | number
------------
1. | 1
2. | 2
3. | 3
4. | 4
5. | 5
6. | 6
7. | 7 
8. | 8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and it is not painfull - use a *Cartesian* query.

First, create a small query returning 10 records:

```sql
SELECT 
    DISTINCT Abs([id] Mod 10) AS N
FROM 
    MSysObjects;
```

Save it as `Ten`.

Then run this simple query:

```sql
SELECT 
    [Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100+[Ten_3].[N]*1000+[Ten_4].[N]*10000+[Ten_5].[N]*100000 AS Id
FROM 
    Ten AS Ten_0, 
    Ten AS Ten_1, 
    Ten AS Ten_2, 
    Ten AS Ten_3, 
    Ten AS Ten_4, 
    Ten AS Ten_5
```

which, in two seconds, will return Id from 0 to 999999.

Answer (score 1):

Very painful but you can do the following:

```
create table numbers (
    id int autoincrement,
    number int
);

-- 1 row
insert into numbers (number) values (1);

-- 2 rows
insert into numbers (number) select number from numbers;

-- 4 rows
insert into numbers (number) select number from numbers;

-- 8 rows
insert into numbers (number) select number from numbers;

-- repeat a total of 20 times
```

The value of `number` is always `1`, but `id` increments.  You can make them equal using an `update`:

```
update numbers
    set number = id;
```

Answer (score -1):

If this were SQL server you could use a recursive CTE to do this.

```
WITH number 
AS
(
    SELECT num = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num + 1
    from number
    where num < 1000000
)
SELECT num FROM number
option(maxrecursion 0)
```

But you are asking about MS Access, since access does not support recursive CTEs, you can try doing it with a macro and insert it into a table and read it out?