# Split multi-value field into different rows using SQL in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I’ve got a simple table in Microsoft Access that looks like this:

| Primary Key | Applications List |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | `<Value>|<Value>,<Value>|<Value>` |
| 456 | `<Value>|<Value>,<Value>|<Value>` |

I need to break out the list of applications into separate rows using the “,” as a delimiter so the end result is a table that looks like this:

| Primary Key | Applications List |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | `<Value>|<Value>` |
| 123 | `<Value>|<Value>` |
| 456 | `<Value>|<Value>` |
| 456 | `<Value>|<Value>` |

I’ve tried using the Split function but can’t figure out how to split on the “,” and output the results to a different row like the second table above. I would greatly appreciate your help figuring this one out. Thanks so much!

Comment: Do they always have four values, pairs separated by comma (ie will each row always become two rows, not more, not less)?

Comment: No, there could be 2 values or 10 values; however, they are always separated by a comma.

Comment: The reason I asked was that, if you could put a reasonable limit on them, you could  use multiple unions each selecting one field. If the number of values are unknown there is no SQL capability in msaccess to do it. But you can use vba to split and insert into a table, and then you can select from that table

Answer (score 0):

If you can put a limit on the length of **Application List** you can build a number table

```
CREATE TABLE NumTable (ID integer)
```

up-front with as many rows as there are characters in the longest **Application List**. Assuming that the longest [Application List] is 1000 characters long, ID=1, ID=2, ..., ID=1000), and then use something like this:

```
select T.[Primary Key], 
       mid(T.AL,NT.ID+1
           , iif(instr(NT.ID+1,t.AL,',')>0
           ,     instr(NT.ID+1,t.AL,',')-1-nt.ID,1000)) as 
from (select [Primary Key], ',' & [Application List] as AL from tblYourTable) as T
     inner join
     NumTable as NT
     on mid(t.AL,NT.ID,1)=','
```

You can build the number table in EXCEL and paste it; or write a little VBA routine, or even create it dynamically (*).

I can't imagine it performing very well if the volume is high.

Let us know how you proceed!

(*)[Generate numbers 1 to 1000000 in MS Access using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68411257/generate-numbers-1-to-1000000-in-ms-access-using-sql)

Answer (score 0):

If you setup a Table1 and a Table2 with the same field names, you can run this function to do it for you - it basically loops through Table1 records, splits the Applications List into multiple fields and then inserts new records for each field.

```
Public Sub SplitDataIntoNewTable()

    Const DATA_SEPARATOR    As String = ","
    Dim qdf                 As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rsOld               As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsNew               As DAO.Recordset
    
    Dim i                   As Integer
    Dim lngNumAdded         As Long
    
    Dim lngKey              As Long
    Dim strList             As String
    Dim strNewList          As String
    
    Dim varLists            As Variant
        
    Set rsOld = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table1", dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
    Set rsNew = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table2", dbOpenDynaset)
    
    With rsOld
        While Not .EOF
            lngKey = ![Primary Key]
            strList = ![Applications List]
            varLists = Split(strList, DATA_SEPARATOR)
            With rsNew
                For i = LBound(varLists) To UBound(varLists)
                    ' Add new record for every list split out of old data
                    .AddNew
                    ' Note that this CANNOT actually be defined as a PRIMARY KEY - it will have duplicates
                    ![Primary Key] = lngKey
                    ![Applications List] = varLists(i)
                    lngNumAdded = lngNumAdded + 1
                    .Update
                Next i
            End With
            .MoveNext
        Wend
        
        rsNew.Close
        .Close
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Added " & lngNumAdded & " New Records"
    
    Set rsOld = Nothing
    Set rsNew = Nothing
End Sub
```

For example I had Table1 look like this:

[image: Table 1]

And resulting Table2 ended up like this

[image: Table 2]